# Compress js files in magento - nginx server

Tags: magento, pagespeed

I have created magento website. I want to **increase** the **pagespeed**. For that I want to compress all the **js** files(I got this information from **google pagespeed Insights**). I know If I am using **apache** server means it can be done by uncommenting following line in .htaccess file.

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
```

But I am using **nginx** server. So I don't know how can I solve it. If you know the solution,Kindly post here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use magento default feature for js compress. Go to Systme >> Configuration >> Developer >> JS merge\

Comment: js marge and js compress is same thing?? I don't know That is why I am asking..

Comment: Magento Js merge use for all js combine into one js

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't worry about this too  much but would turn on magentos combined JS and CSS feature. You can enable gzip compression with nginx though by putting something like the following in your nginx conf file;

- gzip on; gzip_proxied any;
- gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript;
- gzip_vary on;
- gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

IE6 has some issues with compression so the last line disables it. There are further options which allow you to set the compression level etc.

Comment: I am slightly confused about js merge and compression. Can you give me the difference if have?

Comment: Merging the files means that rather than server all the individual JS files and CSS files for which there could be numerous, they are all merged into one. i.e. 10 files become 1. This saves on required connections to server when downloading the page and assets. Compression, simply compresses the assets with gzip, which the browser then decompresses when it downloads the asset. Don't forget that with compression, there is an overhead on the server compressing the data and for the clients browser to decompress the data once it's received it.

Comment: Use gzip, that is what PageSpeed is telling you to do.